# Python JSON to CSV conversion not displaying correctly

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to take some JSON, flatten it, convert it to a CSV, and write it locally. I've tried the code below and it is not displaying as intended.

```
import json
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# The JSON Object
sample_object = {'Name':'John', 'Location':{'City':'Los Angeles','State':'CA'}, 'hobbies':['Music', 'Running']}

# This part flattens the JSON object.
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[str(name[:-1])] = str(x)

    flatten(y)
    return out

flat = flatten_json(sample_object)

# This part writes the flattened JSON object to CSV. 
with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(flat)
```

It comes out as a CSV incorrectly with each character in one field and only headers. I am trying to have it display properly as such:

```
Name, Location_City, Location_State, Hobbies_01, Hobbies_02
John, "Los Angeles", CA, Music, Running
```

I'm running Python 2.7.11 with Pandas

Comment: Small note: remove the spaces after the `,`. Some csv parsers can have trouble with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from csv module.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.DictWriter(fp, delimiter=',', fieldnames=flat.keys())
    a.writeheader()
    a.writerow(flat)
```

The headers will appear in an undefined order though here, since it depends on the return value of the `keys` method. You can change this by setting the list of field names manually.
Note that in your example the field names for hobbies are `hobbies_0, hobbies_1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very close, I think you just need to use `csv.DictWriter` instead of `csv.writer` because you are passing in a dictionary which is a mapping of field names to values.

If you want your csv file to have a header, you'll also need to call `a.writeheader()` before calling `a.writerows(flat)`.